# Unresponsive Server 2012, may be because of Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v, memory-usage

there is a setup: ProLiant, Xeon, 16Gb on the host, 3 VMs (2 servers 2012 + Win7). Not all three VMs work simultaneously all the time.

The problem is that sometimes host (and mostly all guests) become unresponsive. "Unresponsive" means that I can't login (or it's going very slow) to either machine, and most of host's services stop working.
Sometimes host stops operating normally but guest still work (slow, but work).

It's definitely tied to VM's workload and I feel that it's tied to memory demand on VM.

The actual problems: 
- even if I able to properly shutdown "problematic" VM (or even all VMs), host doesn't recover. I should reboot it anyway;
- I don't see any specific errors in event viewer anywhere. Performance counters (memory, processors) also do not show any obvious problems.

Could you advice me direction to dig into?

Comment: first off, server updated ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Host and all VMs are up to date.

Comment: I guess Integration Services and Virtual Machine Drivers are installed in the VM correctly ?

Comment: In Win7 yes, in Server 2012 VMs I guess not needed

Comment: It's needed in all VM :)

Comment: I checked it out. Latest version of integration services was automatically updated on Server 2012 VMs. It doesn't need to be updated manually.